# SQL Error: ORA-00904: invalid identifier - Send to oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

What is wrong with this query im sending to oracle?

This is my code:

```
manager.Insert("UPDATE WEDSTRIJD SET UITSLAG ='" + uitslag + "'  WHERE WedstrijdNr =" + nummer2);
```

This is being send:

```
UPDATE WEDSTRIJD SET Uitslag = '21-2' WHERE WEDSTRIJDNR = 14;
```

But how can I change that to?

I need this query:

```
UPDATE WEDSTRIJD SET "Uitslag" = '21-2' WHERE  "WedstrijdNr" = 14;
```

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER use string concatenation like this with SQL queries.  You're asking to be the victim of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Use parameters instead.  Please.

Comment: It is a small project for school, to late now to change to parameters. But ye i know what ya mean.

Comment: If you use parameters you might still find the issue.  Sometimes the simple change from string concatenation to parameters highlights the real problem.

Comment: Wait what? You have the variable uitslag that has the value "21-2" and you want it to be "1-12"?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall thats not the real thing i need to know, thats just a bad mistake xD

Comment: @GrantWinney uitslag value is good, but when i execute the Query, "WEDSTRIJDNR" Invalid Identifier... So my syntax is bad i qeuss, but i cant find the error for a hour now.

Comment: That means that either your table doesn't exist, or you're connected to the wrong schema.  Are you sure the table exists, and are you sure that it exists in the schema you're connecting to?

Comment: @MauriceReeves Im sure that the table exist and the connection is open, cause a few other of my Querys like: string commandstring = "SELECT * FROM GEBRUIKER"; does work..

Comment: That's a different table.  Try running `SELECT * FROM WEDSTRIJDNR` from your app right now and see what happens.

Comment: Also, it might be the column name is different, so the table exists, but the column name isn't there.  Did you add the column recently?

Comment: @MauriceReeves the table 'WEdstrijdNR' doesn't exist, but the table 'Wedstrijd' does.

Comment: Right, I saw that after I added my comment, that's the column name.  Did you try selecting from that column from that table via your app?

Comment: @MauriceReeves No, but the column is for the where statement.

Comment: Show us your DDL please.

Comment: @MauriceReeves DDL? sorry

Comment: The SQL script you used to create the table.  I think the problem is with casing.  Oracle is picky about cases and using double quotes forces Oracle to match things up with strict casing.

Comment: I can't see how you got any of that query to work, with double quotes around your field names.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is with upper and lower case, which is why you need the column names to be in quotes? If so then you should quote the names in your query string:

```
manager.Insert("UPDATE WEDSTRIJD SET \"Uitslag\" = '" + uitslag + "' WHERE \"WedstrijdNr\" = " + nummer2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesnt need to be in Quotes but Oracle has to execute the query. Still this above doesnt work.

Comment: Doesn't it exactly create the query you said you needed? What error do you get?